# 5 star rating system database design

Tags: ios, swift, algorithm, rating

Im building an app that will have a feature that allows you to rate users on a scale from 1-5. I've already decided I'm going to use a weighted average like so:

`Sum of (weight * number of reviews at that weight) / total number of reviews`

Im having trouble figuring out how to store this data using firebase, since I need this rating value to initialize a `User` object. I thought of storing each rating as a dictionary where key is `id` of user leaving review, and value is the actual rating. Then after I fetch user from database and need to initialize `User` I do the following:

```
    // keep track of amount of each rating. 
    var oneStars = 0
    var twoStars = 0
    var threeStars = 0
    var fourStars = 0
    var fiveStars = 0

    // iterate through dictionary of ratings where key is unique Id, and value is star rating.
    for (key, value) in ratings {
        switch value {
        case 1: oneStars += 1
        case 2: twoStars += 1
        case 3: threeStars += 1
        case 4: fourStars += 1
        case 5: fiveStars += 1
        }
    }

    let weightedSum = (
        (5 * fiveStars) +
        (4 * fourStars) +
        (3 * threeStars) +
        (2 * twoStars) +
        (1 * oneStars)
    )

    let reviewsSum = oneStars + twoStars + threeStars + fourStars + fiveStars

    let rating = weightedSum / reviewsSum

    let user = User(name: "john doe", rating: rating)
```

Is this the best way to store ratings, and do actual calculation to initialize object, or is there a more efficient design? Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You probably need to store the rating of each user, so it's fine to store ratings in this way.

As for calculating the final rating, here is a better implementation:

```
var count = 0
var rating = 0

for (key, value) in ratings {
    count += 1
    rating += value
}

rating /= count

let user = User(name: "john doe", rating: rating)
```

Another algorithm that can deal with huge amount of ratings witch could lead to overflow:

```
var count = 0
var rating = 0

for (key, value) in ratings {
    count += 1
    rating += (value - rating) / count
}

let user = User(name: "john doe", rating: rating)
```

The second algorithm works great if you recalculate the ratings on the server side each time a new user rates (in case you have a huge amount of users accessing those ratings, and also huge amounts of ratings, it's better to calculate this on the server-side).